# How does '==' work with UIViewControllers?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

In a tutorial for using `UIPageViewController`, there's a code that goes like this:

```
if self == parent.pages.first {
    self.label_Back.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
}
```

Which basically checks if the `self` is the first controller stack. How does this work?

And also, if we have multiple instances of a controller class in `pages` array of `UIViewController`, will doing the `firstIndex` thing like below work?

```
/**
 Notifies '_tutorialDelegate' that the current page index was updated.
 */
private func notifyTutorialDelegateOfNewIndex() {
    if let firstViewController = viewControllers?.first,
        let index = self.pages.firstIndex(of: firstViewController) {
            tutorialDelegate?.tutorialPageViewController(tutorialPageViewController: self, didUpdatePageIndex: index)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
if self == parent.pages.first
```

These are Cocoa (Objective-C) objects — UIViewController, descended from NSObject:

- Swift `==` on an Objective-C object in the absence of an override calls `isEqual:`, inherited from NSObject.
- For an NSObject, in the absence of an override, `isEqual:` defaults to object identity.

So this is just like Swift `===`, i.e. it is true just in case these are identically the same view controller object.